# Copy the command of a button in tkinter onto another button

Tags: python, tkinter

Given a tkinter button with a command, I would like to copy its function call to replicate it when another button is pushed. I've tried with something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

btn1 = tk.Button(root, text='Button 1', command=lambda: print('Button hit'))
btn2 = tk.Button(root, text='Button 2', command=None)

# Here the magic should occur
btn2.configure(command=btn1.configure()['command'])

btn1.grid(row=0, column=0)
btn2.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

But unfortunately button 2 does not call the function.

Here you see an simplified version of the problem. Actually the two buttons are in two very different parts of the script, so it is very inconvenient to move a function along.

Comment: did you check what `btn1.configure()['command']` returns? it should be `btn1.configure()['command'][-1]` or a way shorter option is this: `btn1.cget('command')` or `btn1['command']` and after all why not just `btn2 = tk.Button(root, text='Button 2', command=btn1['command'])`

Comment: You can just add the same command to the another button

Comment: Definitely easier than expected. Basically I was copying other features by using `.configure()` and I couldn't get why command wasn't working (btw it would make sense to make the command work even passing the whole line...). And I've added a `.configure(_)` line for `btn2` just to make it explicit. Thank you very much @Matiiss

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I've solved the problem in two steps.

1. In the proposed code I had wrongly used `btn1.configure()['command']` instead of `btn1.cget('command')` as @Matiiss correctly suggested.
2. In my original code I was destroying `btn1` after assigning its command to `btn2`, however this made me lose command. Substituting `destroy` with proper`forget` I was able to correctly pass the command.